# Durandal third-level subrouting

Tags: durandal, durandal-2.0, durandal-navigation

I'm trying to make child router of a child router in **Durandal.js**, but getting random dumb errors (for example 404 etc.). Is it Durandal's issue (I mean if it has not third-level subrouting support) or it's maybe my code problem?

Thanks

---

Anyways, I'm going to include my code here:

returning **shell**

```
return {
    router: router,
    activate: function () {
        return router.map([

            {
                route: ['', 'Main'],
                moduleId: 'Main/index',
                nav: false
            },

            {
                route: 'Main*details',
                moduleId: 'Main/index',
                hash: '#/Main/',
                title: 'Main',
                nav: false
            }

        ]).buildNavigationModel()
          .activate();
    }
};
```

returning **2nd level child**

```
var mainRouter = router.createChildRouter()
    .makeRelative({
        moduleId: 'Main',
        fromParent: true
    }).map([

        {
            route: ['', 'Dashboard'],
            moduleId: 'Dashboard/index',
            nav: false
        },

        {
            route: 'Dashboard*details',
            moduleId: 'Dashboard/index',
            hash: '#/Main/Dashboard',
            title: 'Dashboard',
            nav: true
        }

    ]).buildNavigationModel();

return {
    router: mainRouter
}
```

returning **3rd level child**

```
var dashboardRouter = router.createChildRouter()
    .makeRelative({
        moduleId:'Dashboard',
        fromParent: true
    }).map([

        {
            route: ['', 'Product'],
            moduleId: 'Product/index',
            hash: '#/Main/Dashboard/Product',
            title: 'Product',
            nav: true
        }

    ]).buildNavigationModel();

return {
    router: dashboardRouter
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe it's currently a bug in child routers that are at the 3rd level or below. We have this tracked as an issue and are working on a solution. I apologize for the inconvenience.

Comment: :( Thank you a lot for the reply, can you give a issue link of Github? Just want to subscribe if there will be fix of this issue.

Comment: We actually have this kind of problem in our application but instead of having 404, the view bindings are cleared when navigating back to a child. Looking forward for a fix :)

Answer (score -1):

hah... This is quite simple:

```
(var dashboardRouter = router.createChildRouter()
.makeRelative({
    moduleId:'Dashboard',
    fromParent: true
}).map([

    {
        route: ['', 'Product'],
        moduleId: 'Product/index',
        hash: '#/Main/Dashboard/Product',
        title: 'Product',
        nav: true
    }

]).buildNavigationModel();

return {
    router: dashboardRouter
}).makeRelative({
    moduleId: 'Main',
    fromParent: true
}).map([

    {
        route: ['', 'Dashboard'],
        moduleId: 'Dashboard/index',
        nav: false
    },

    {
        route: 'Dashboard*details',
        moduleId: 'Dashboard/index',
        hash: '#/Main/Dashboard',
        title: 'დეშბორდი',
        tab: "dashboard",
        nav: true
    }

]).buildNavigationModel();

return {
    router: mainRouter
}
```